# How to pass in a variable into position{}

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Hi I'm trying to pass in a variable into the below code.

```
position: {lat: 37.869, lng: -122.255}
```

I would like to pass in a variable latitude and variable longitude.

How can I go about doing this?

**Secondary Question**

```
var street_options = {
  zoom: 1,
  position: {lat: 37.869, lng: -122.255},
  pov: {heading: 165, pitch: 0},
};
```

Is there an alternative to the **position:{}** so I can pass in the LatLng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Just create a couple of variables and refer to them directly in that code:

```
var lat = 37.869, lng = -122.255;

... 

position: {lat: lat, lng: lng}
```

Or perhaps construct an object that contains both:

```
var coords = {lat: 37.869, lng: -122.255};

... 

position: coords
```

2:  use the LatLng constructor like so:

```
var street_options = {
  zoom: 1,
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.869, -122.255),
  pov: {heading: 165, pitch: 0},
};
```

Or the same but using variables:

```
var street_options = {
  zoom: 1,
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  pov: {heading: 165, pitch: 0},
};
```

Or maybe construct that LatLng object previously, and then refer to it in the options:

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

var street_options = {
  zoom: 1,
  position: latLng ,
  pov: {heading: 165, pitch: 0},
};
```

Comment: Thanks, you explained it very well. I was led to the conclusion that the google maps and street view have different latitude and longitude co-ordinates.